# Not able to decrypt data with wasm-themis token protected mode in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript

this is the function which i used to decrypt the string with data and token :

```
import themis from "wasm-themis";


export const stringDec = async (str: string) => {
  try {
    var masterKey = Buffer.from(
      "mykey",
      "base64"
    );
    var mkey = Buffer.from(masterKey.toString("base64"));

    var message = JSON.parse(str);
    
    let symmetricKey = new themis.SymmetricKey(mkey)
    let scellTP = themis.SecureCellTokenProtect.withKey(symmetricKey);
    let encData = {
      data: Buffer.from(message.hash, 'base64'),
      token: Buffer.from(message.token, 'base64')
    }
    try {
      let decrypted = scellTP.decrypt(encData.data, encData.token)  
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error", error);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

Anyone have idea on same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the issue? Is there any error etc?

Comment: TypeError:  cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'allocate')